# How to hide the popup of URL in UIwebview

Tags: iphone, safari, uiwebview

I have UIwebview. While keep on clicking on a hyperlink or button on UIwebview , one small bar of URL is appearing. How i can hide that ? In Iphone applications using IUI with UIwebview , this address popup bar is a distraction.  Will you please answer me  ? Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it....am answering to my own question.

http://www.macoscoders.com/tag/webkittouchcallout/

document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";

this code did the trick.....

Comment: its here also

http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/